# Hyper-V server 2016 and 2012R2 Replica compatibility

Tags: hyper-v

Can Hyper-V Server 2012R2 and 2016 run as replica servers? It is mainly for upgrade the environment, but I need the replication is working for some time between 2012R2 and 2016.
Do anyone try it, or do you know any source regarding the compatibility?

Best regards,

Jan

Comment: Why not perform a rolling Hyper-V Cluster upgrade instead?

Comment: It is not a cluster, only bunch of servers that are replicating some machines

Comment: Could you clarify, what you are going to replicate? Also what software for replication you want to use?

Comment: Im replicating virtual machines, Im using Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 and its native console...

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find official confirmation. But found a workaround. Take a look at this blog:

http://blog.fedenko.info/2016/06/hyper-v-replica-with-self-signed.html

You need to add certificates on both hosts and enable replication on a VM side.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Im able to replicate between two servers Windows Hyper-V Server 2012 R2. Both in active direktory, Kerberos authenticated. Question was about cross version support - since Im able to manage 2012R2 from 2016 console and 2016 server from 2012 R2 console. Question was if Im able to replicate across the versions...

Answer (score 0):

Target OS must be the same or Newer then the Source OS.

so you can replicate from 2012 to 2016 but Not from 2016 to 2012.

Comment: Im trying it right now, but I ends up with 0x00002EFE, The connection with the server was terminated abnormally. It is from 2012R2 -> 2016 Hyper-V server - it is between two locations, in each location there are servers with the same versions. in locations internally it is working perfect. All the servers are in the same domain. Im using Kerberos auth.